# SwiftUI Form NavigationButton Style

Tags: forms, swiftui

How can I change the navigation button in form.

```
 Section {
     NavigationLink(
        destination: SignUpView(),
           label: {
            Text("Don't have an account?")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
     })
 }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change its color to black?

Comment: No, sory for screenshot. I want to only text in form like as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add that link as footer of previous Section (that one containing *Forgot Password?*), like

[image: demo]

```
Section(footer:
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        NavigationLink(
            destination: SignUpView(),
            label: {
                 Text("Don't have an account?")
                      .foregroundColor(.gray)
        })
    }) {
```

Tested and worked with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

Comment: Thank you this solution works great. But when I use .sheet in SignUpView, it automatically dismisses itself.